Azure function is executing 10x more frequently than scheduled
Why this function runs almost every 3 minutes, instead of 30 minutes ?
app.timer("randomFunction", {
  schedule: "0 */30 * * * *",
  runOnStartup: true,
  handler: async (myTimer, context) => {}})


Invocations:

Also tried with:
schedule: "*/30 * * * *"


Use this cron "0 */30 * * * *"

@RithwikBojja - did you not notice that is what OP is (incorrectly if it's crontab) using?

runOnStartup is probably a bad idea. It'll make it run at arbitrary times. As the documentation says, "runOnStartup should rarely if ever be set to true, especially in production."

@GuyIncognito w ill try that. Thanks!

@CesarBhering, check if below solution helps.

Thanks @GuyIncognito for the comments.
I agree with @GuyIncognito regarding runOnStartup. This setting makes code execute at highly unpredictable times hence it is not recommended to use runOnStartup setting in production, refer the blog by @TOM.
RunOnStartup refers to the startup of each host. If RunOnStartup set to true, the runtime starts when the function app wakes up after going idle due to inactivity, when the function app restarts due to function changes, and when the function app scales out.
I faced the same issue when I set RunOnStartup to true in my function code.

Use below function code to trigger the timer function for every 30 minutes.
Code snippet:
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.timer('timerTrigger', {
    schedule: '0 */30 * * * *',
    handler: (myTimer, context) => {
        context.log('Timer function processed request.');
    }
});

Able to trigger the timer function for every 30 minutes.
Portal:

